# Getting null value using map in Rails

Tags: ruby

I am getting null value when I am using if condition inside a map. I have an array and I looping through that.

My first array is:

```
[
    {
        id: 5,
        Vegetables: "Cabbage",
        Area: 39,
        Production: 695.33,
        Year: 2014,
        created_at: "2018-07-18T06:23:11.000Z",
        updated_at: "2018-07-18T06:23:11.000Z"
    },
    {
        id: 12,
        Vegetables: "Bittergourd",
        Area: 9.71,
        Production: 67.25,
        Year: 2014,
        created_at: "2018-07-18T06:23:11.000Z",
        updated_at: "2018-07-18T06:23:11.000Z"
    },
    # .....
]
```

This is my array and and I using this code to loop:

```
ji1 = ["Cabbage","Bittergourd"]
hash_data = ji1.map do |col|
  dataset = col.to_s.gsub("_"," ")
  {
    type: views,
    legendText: dataset,
    showInLegend: true,
    dataPoints: b.reject{ |x| x["Districts"] == "Bihar" }.map do |el|
      if el["Vegetables"] == "Bittergourd"
        { y: el["Area"], label: el["Year"] }
      end
    end
  }
end
```

In this example `b` is my array I am getting this value. I want a result like this:

```
[
  {
    type: "column",
    legendText: "Cabbage",
    showInLegend: true,
    dataPoints: [
      {
        y: 9.7,
        label: 2014
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    type: "column",
    legendText: "Bittergourd",
    showInLegend: true,
    dataPoints: [
      {
        y: 39,
        label: 2014
      }
      # .....
    ]
  }
]
```

When I am running my loop I am getting a `null` value. Is there any way I can create a result like above using `map` with my array?

Comment: I don't see where some of the information should be coming from. For instance, where is the variable `view` coming from in: `type:views`?

Comment: you can put anything it doesn't matter

Comment: Why don't you just loop through the hash and add an extra key to it on each iteration? This sample code doesn't make sense to me, so can't help you with the exact code, without seeing where the variables (like view) are being declared.

Comment: actual data is https://gist.github.com/nwoow/a5ce22fbae020925c2e52b0f7730c72a

Comment: If `view` in `type:views` "doesn't matter", change your example to one that that is complete, rather than asking each reader who wants to run your code to change it in some arbitrary manner. If `b` is your "first array", write `b = [{ id: 5,...}`. More generally, when you give an example, make all values valid Ruby objects, assign a variable to each input object (so that readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments), make the example as  concise as possible and show your desired result (a Ruby object). Lastly, there's an object `nil`, but "null" is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being `b` the data you provided, and removing views since I don't know where that variable comes from... try this piece of code. I believe it achieves what you are trying to do

```
    grouped_data = b.group_by{ |data| data[:Vegetables]}

    grouped_data.map{ |vegetable, values| 
        dataset = vegetable.to_s.gsub("_"," ")
        {

          legendText: dataset,
          showInLegend: true,
          dataPoints: values.map { |value|
            { y: value[:Area], label: value[:Year] }
          }
        }
     }
```

**Update**

Without using `group_by`:

```
vegetables_hash = Hash.new
b.each { |data| 
    dataset = data[:Vegetables].to_s.gsub("_"," ")
    vegetables_hash[dataset] ||= { legendtext: dataset, showInLegend: true, dataPoints: []}
    vegetables_hash[dataset][:dataPoints].push({ y: data[:Area], label: data[:Year] })
}
```

`vegetables_hash` has data grouped by vegetables in the desired format.
Last step:

```
vegetables_hash.values
```

Comment: yes it is working is there any way to group data without group_by

Comment: There you go. I updated the answer in order to not use `group_by`. There are many ways to do this. I hope those helped.